# "if string in" returning False

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I am creating a text based game for a Python class.

I created a dictionary for my rooms and created a list for my directions:

```py
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {
        'name': 'Great Hall',
        'South': 'Bedroom'
    },
    'Bedroom': {
        'name': 'Bedroom',
        'North': 'Great Hall',
        'East': 'Cellar'
    },
    'Cellar': {
        'name': 'Cellar',
        'West': 'Bedroom'
    }
}

directions = [
    'North',
    'South',
    'East',
    'West'
]
```

Here is the code snippet with my `if` statement:

```py
current_room = rooms['Great Hall']

while True:
    print('You are in', current_room['name'])
    command = input('What would you like to do? ')

    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            print('Nothing happened')
    elif command == 'Quit':
        print('Goodbye')
        break
```

The `if` statement returns `True` if the user inputs the command something like `South`, but does not return `True` if the user inputs the command `Go South`. If the string `South` is in the string `Go South`, why wouldn't this return `True`? What can I change for it to return `True`?

Comment: Where do you think `"South" in "Go South"` or `"Go South" in "Go South"` is evaluated in this code?

Comment: the "if command in directions" statement.

Comment: So you think that `directions` is equal to the string `"Go South"`? Have you checked if this is true?

Comment: @LaLoba `directions` is not a string, is a list. Check [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74548774/15032126). Maybe you want to check if `command`is in an item contained in `directions`?

Comment: "South" is in my list "directions". The string "Go South" contains the string "South".  This was my logic in  assuming that it would evaluate to true

Answer (score 3):

##### Let's reduce your problem down some more:

It seems to me this is all the code that is necessary to describe your problem:

```
   directions = ['South', 'North', 'East', 'West']
   command = 'South'
   if command in directions:
     print('This works as LaLoba expects')
   
   command = 'Go South'
   if command in directions:
     print('This line of code does not execute, but LaLoba would like it to.')
```

##### What's happening:

Let's think of the in operator as a function:

```
def is_element_in_container(thing_im_searching_for, container):
  for element in container:
    if element == thing_im_searching_for:
      return True
  return False
```

Given this, the string `'Go South'` is clearly not in the container, so it would fail to match.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you have any advice on what I can add to my code so that a command like "Go south" would evaluate to true? Sorry, I am still learning and very new with all of this.

Comment: @LaLoba: It's actually more complicated than you're thinking. What if the user writes `"Go North West"`. Should that result in `"North"`, `"West"` or an error?

Answer (score 0):

Note that when asking
`if command in directions:` you actually searching if the `command` is an element of the list `directions`.

Your intention is to ask if `command` is a part (substring) of one of the element in the `direction` list.

So, something like:

```
if any(single_direction in command for single_direction in directions)
```

would return true.(Since now you ask, for any direction, if its in what the user has inputed)

However, take into consideration you should also treat the various options for the user input also in your `rooms` map.